# How can I copy variable file from bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, backup

I run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
date=$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' )
file="mysql_dump_$date"

echo '###Start DB Backup '$date'###'
        mysqldump -h localhost -u 'USERNAME' -pPASSWD 'DBNAME' > /backup/$file
echo '###DB Backuo Finished '$date'###'
} >> /backup/backup.log
```

As you can see in the mysqldump line, $file will be named mysql_dump_date

I would like to cp the file somewhere else but don't know how I can specify to use the $file which is used in the mysqldump line. Obviously, I could just used $file but if the DB backup starts at 10:49:59 and the cp will start at 10:50:00, it won't have the same timestamp and wouldn't be able to find the file and the copy would fail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your doubt. You seem to think that `$file` will change its value if it is used a second time.

Bash variables don't change their values. `$date` and `$file` are set once in your script, and then they keep the same value until they disappear at the end of the script (unless they are reassigned). So you can just use `$file` again, and it will have the same value.